# Rewrite .htacces first directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

This is the address I would like to use:

**http://mydomain.com/cars**

and I want to redirect ** http://mydomain.com/category/product.php?code=cars **

But I'm confused...  becouse I'm able to do this only if I have my cars in a subdirectory

So this is working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/?$ /category/product.php?url=$1 [L]
```

How  have I to change my rule to works like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /category/product.php?url=$1 [L]  ??
```

Thanks for you help.  I was looking for a solution but I have not found it....

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /category/product.php?code=$1 [L]
```